# Which Is Correct: "Do More Faster" or "Do More, Faster"?

Tags: writing, sentence

I have been stumbling with this phrase for a few days now. I read a book the other day called "Do More Faster". The title comes from a slogan about startups getting more work done than their competition, and getting work done faster.

However, to me the sentence sounds like it is talking about making the "more" faster instead of making the "do" both more and faster. The way I would write the phase would be to add a comma after more: "Do More, Faster".

Which Is Correct: "Do More Faster" or "Do More, Faster"?

Answer (score 2):

"Do More Faster" (no comma), because it provides no break or breathing-space, successfully suggests the speediness that the book is trying to promote.

Answer (score 2):

"Do More Faster" confuses two grammatical roles of "more." The book's author intends it to mean "More (Things/Projects/Work/etc.)," and you can see that the comma wouldn't be necessary if the noun were included thus: "Do More Work Faster." Written without the comma, however, it makes "More" seem as if it modifies "Faster," and that would be grammatically incorrect. ("More faster" is certainly unacceptable.)

Therefore, "Do More, Faster," would be my preference for clarity, but if we accept the author's intention in using "More" as a noun, the comma becomes unnecessary. (And I agree with Martha's point about this usage being a title; in that context, the comma's absence is more acceptable.)

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, and while I can see where you're coming from with the meaning distinction you make, I think the intended meaning of both is the same (i.e. both "more" and "faster" apply to "do"). The version with a comma is somewhat more clear, but I can totally see omitting the comma in a title.

Comment: For me, this reads as if it's about doing "faster" (whatever product or service that would be ;-)), but more of it.  Especially since "Do faster"... well, it may not be *wrong*, but it certainly sounds a bit weird.

Comment: If 'more faster' is correct, 'most fastest' should also be correct, but....I would say, double comparative should be avoided.  A comma, like "Do more, faster...' is proximate to saying, Do more... do faster...'

Comment: @RamPillai: why do you think "more faster" implies "most fastest"? Can you give me an example of words that actually work that way?

Comment: "more faster" is double comparative. "Most fastest" is double superlative.  These are against the accepted grammar rules.  The learner learns in the order, fast, faster, fastest.  Faster per se equals more fast; and fastest, most fast; Here, if one says more faster, and most fastest, it becomes redundant, besides killing the beauty of sentence.

Comment: @RamPillai: except it's not "more faster [object]". It's an imperative: do more and do it faster, except shortened to make it work better for a title. If you wanted to use the superlative, it'd need to become "Do the most the fastest".

Comment: @Martha, If 'do more, faster' = 'do more; do faster', it makes sense. I tend to disagree with 'more faster' as in  'Do more faster' or most fastest, as in 'do the most the faster', because it  confuses, which can be set right by inserting a comma, like do more, faster, and, 'do the most, the fastest'.